# Обновление элементов в ComboBox после Get запроса

Tags: c#

У меня после запроса приходит список, который я заполняю в Combobox. У меня получается так, что после нового запроса список в Combobox дополняется, а не обновляется. В связи с этим у меня вопрос, как мне сделать обновление списка? Стоит уточнить, что новый список приходит после каждого изменения свойства Text.
Программный код:

```
private void InputComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = @"https://www.multitran.com/ms.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=" + InputComboBox.Text;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Referer = "https://www.multitran.com/";
            try
            {

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

                string[] strMass = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(' ');
                for (int i = 0; i < strMass.Length; i++)
                {
                    InputComboBox.Items.Add(strMass[i]);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something wrong...");
            }
```

Comment: Что если перед добавлением элементов в комбобокс, вызвать `InputComboBox.Items.Clear()`?

Comment: @tym32167 тогда при вводе маркер всегда встаёт в начало и при выборе слова из этого списка это же слово удаляется

Comment: ну вы попробуйте сохранить слово, что было выбрано, и после обновления комбобокса, выбрать его снова?

Answer (score 1):

Немного переписал ваш код. Вашу проблему не воспроизвел, но всё равно решил кодом поделиться, может будет вам полезно.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
//  IDisposable textBoxSubscriber;
```

Конструктор формы. Просто создаем контролы и подписываемся

```
    public MyForm()
    {
        this.Width = 400;
        this.Height = 200;

        var tb = new TextBox() { Width = 200, Left = 10, Top = 10 };
        this.Controls.Add(tb);

        var cb = new ComboBox() { Width = 200, Left = 10, Top = 35 };
        this.Controls.Add(cb);

//      Если использовать пакет System.Reactive и троттлить событие текстбокса одной секундой. 
//      textBoxSubscriber = Observable
//              .FromEventPattern(h => tb.TextChanged += h, h => tb.TextChanged -= h)
//              .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
//              .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
//              .Subscribe(async x => RefreshComboBox(cb, await GetWords(tb.Text)));


        // Если НЕ использовать пакет System.Reactive, а просто подписаться на текстбокс
        tb.TextChanged+= async (sender, args) => RefreshComboBox(cb, await GetWords(tb.Text));
    }
```

Обновлялка комбобокса

```
    void RefreshComboBox(ComboBox cb, string[] words)
    {       
        cb.Items.Clear();
        cb.Items.AddRange(words);                                        
    }
```

Работа с сетью, переделал на асинхронную

```
    async Task<string[]> GetWords(string filter)
    {
        string url = @"https://www.multitran.com/ms.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=" + filter;
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var ret = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

                string[] strMass = ret.Split(new[] { " ", Environment.NewLine }, 
                                                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Distinct()
                    .OrderBy(x => x)
                    .ToArray();

                return strMass;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something wrong...");
            return new string[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Вызов этой красоты

```
var f = new MyForm();
f.ShowDialog();
```

В работе:

[image: ...]